# AngularJS linky filter throws an "Unknown Provider" error

Tags: angularjs

Here is the JSFiddle that shows what I'm doing, simply adding a filter to name.

http://jsfiddle.net/9Z5SJ/1/

```
Error: Unknown provider: linkyFilterProvider <- linkyFilter
    at Error (unknown source)
    at http://code.angularjs.org/angular-1.0.0rc10.js:2530:15
    at Object.getService [as get] (http://code.angularjs.org/angular-1.0.0rc10.js:2658:39)
    at http://code.angularjs.org/angular-1.0.0rc10.js:2535:45
    at Object.getService [as get] (http://code.angularjs.org/angular-1.0.0rc10.js:2658:39)
    at http://code.angularjs.org/angular-1.0.0rc10.js:8956:24
    at filter (http://code.angularjs.org/angular-1.0.0rc10.js:5744:14)
    at _filterChain (http://code.angularjs.org/angular-1.0.0rc10.js:5735:41)
    at statements (http://code.angularjs.org/angular-1.0.0rc10.js:5711:25)
    at parser (http://code.angularjs.org/angular-1.0.0rc10.js:5644:13)
```

Documentation on the *linky* filter
http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.module.ngSanitize.filter.linky

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to load and include the "sanitize" module to use "linky":

Look for these two things:
1. I added "http://docs.angularjs.org/angular-sanitize-1.0.0rc10.min.js" as a resource
2. I linked it into my module by adding "ngSanitize" to angular.module('myApp',['ngSanitize']);

See here:
http://jsfiddle.net/johnlindquist/y2eJL/

Comment: Their documentation does not make this readily apparent. I'm still learning the ins/outs of angularjs.