# Keyword "this" inside angular js controllers

Tags: angularjs

From this URL https://github.com/angular/angular-seed/blob/master/app/js/app.js, I got a controller like below.

```
function WineListCtrl(Wine) {
    this.wines = Wine.query();
}
```

So far what I have been doing in angular is define a controller with $scope getting injected. So i tried, changing the above controller to

```
function WineListCtrl(Wine, $scope) {
    console.log($scope, this)
    this.wines = Wine.query();
}
```

But this is giving an error Error: Unknown provider for `'$scope'`.

I have three questions here:

1. Why the `$scope` of the controller is not injected.
2. Does `this` inside the `WineListCtrl` means the `$scope`.
3. Most of the errors in Angular are of the format 'Unknown provider
   for XXXX'. What should i look for, if the firebug says so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You are using "inferred dependencies" (see [DI page](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di)) which should work fine, unless you minify or obfuscate your JavaScript.
2. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14168699/215945) to this question: ['this' vs $scope in AngularJS controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11605917/this-vs-scope-in-angularjs-controllers)
3. 'Unknown provider' errors normally occur when you forget to use `ng-app` somewhere, or you forget to initialize your app with the appropriate module:

   - [angular js unknown provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12339272/angular-js-unknown-provider)
   - [AngularJS linky filter throws an "Unknown Provider" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10921362/angularjs-linky-filter-throws-an-unknown-provider-error)

Comment: for point 1. I'm not obfuscating any files. Still its throwing the same error, even after adding the inject annotation, below the controller. How can i get access to the `$scope`. Please have a look at the files at http://plnkr.co/edit/F3WOir8KmEAcqSrX0bRI?p=preview

Comment: See http://plnkr.co/edit/K2Q61Bw0w9PnjRdCtvWY?p=preview.  One of your problems is that you need to inject $routeProvider, not $route.  Also, you can't inject $routeProvider in a controller.  See the example on the [$route](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$route) page.  If you want to use/inject $resource, you have to include another .js file.  See the Disqus comments on the [$resource page](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.$resource).

Answer (score 1):

1. When writing your controllers in that form you should inject them with dependencies like so:

   `function WineListCtrl(Wine, $scope) {
       console.log($scope, this)
       this.wines = Wine.query();
   }
   WineListCtrl.$inject = ['Wine', '$scope'];`
2. `this` is not the same as `$scope`. $scope is [an angular-specific object](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope#$new) created with `$rootScope.$new()`
3. See #1

Comment: even after adding `WineListCtrl.$inject = ['Wine', '$scope'];`, i get the same error.

Comment: Can you recreate the problem in jsfiddle or plunker?

Comment: Plunker URL:http://plnkr.co/edit/F3WOir8KmEAcqSrX0bRI?p=preview. Im facing some issues while putting the files in plunker.
But i have attached all the requried files.
The problem is was metioning is in controller.js, at line 24. I have included the inject annotation u have asked to include.